# SQL join not working on SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to cleanse some data and I cannot understand why my simple join will work in a select but not in an update.  Can you please have a quick look and see if you spot anything wrong, I'm stumped.

The select statement:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Description, r.[Media Owner], r.PublicationOwnerId
FROM [dbo].[Retail] r
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PublicationOwner] p
ON r.[Media Owner] = p.Description
AND p.Description IS NOT NULL
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE r SET PublicationOwnerId = p.Id
FROM [dbo].[Retail] r
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PublicationOwner] p
ON r.[Media Owner] = p.Description
AND p.Description IS NOT NULL
```

The select statement returns the correct data, hence I expect the update statement to update [dbo].[Retail].[PublicationOwnerId] to be [dbo].[PublicationOwner].[Id].  BUT it sets all of the PublicationOwnerIds to 1.

Is there something wrong with this update statement, considering that the select works as expected?

Comment: i've checked for locks (row, table), open connections (i'm the only person connected), running transactions (none). i just don't get it.

Comment: also tried casting to same datatype (they are both nvarchar, just different lengths).  this is not necessary, but again the select will work, but the update updates all data to 1.

Comment: YOur query looks fine, perhaps it is something inthe data. PLease show us some sample data and expected resutls.

Comment: I don't think this is part of the problem, but since you're using an inner join, isn't `AND P.Description IS NOT NULL` redundant?

Comment: thanks guys, you prompted me to look elsewhere.  the query was fine of course.  thank you for answering, i couldn't see the wood for the trees.  see my 'answer' below. :S

Answer (score 0):

arrrggh.  I feel like such an idiot, I'd set the Id column (PublicationOwnerId) to be bit.

I'm really embarrassed.  Sorry guys, I should have just taken a walk and came back to it.

Thanks anyhow, for the comments!

---

To clarify for Stefan's benefit:

In SQL Server, if an attempt is made to set a bit field is set to an integer, any value above zero will set the bit to 1 (true).

This was the case with this update statement where I was, incorrectly, trying to set a bit field to an integer value, not understanding why it was set always to a 1 (true) as I believed it to be an integer field.

Comment: Honestly it looks like your data could use some normalization. You are joining these tables on what appears to be varchar data. You also seem to have the same piece of data with different names in different tables. This type of thing will drive you nuts in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Yeah, as above, it's a data cleanse, I'm currently moving it into a manageable format.

Comment: Excellent. Was silently hoping that was what you are doing. I kind of had a feeling that might be the case given the nature of your query. Good luck, that kind of project is challenging to say the least.

Comment: Stefan, I'm not requesting critique or clarification from the author, the author of both the question and the answer is myself.  I hope my explanation may help others.  Thank you.